# How to convert a byte array of Fingerprint Image to iso _19794_2 in Java (Basically Android)?

Tags: java, android, base64, arrays, iso-19794

I have an android device with built-in finger print scanner.

Using this command:

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(model2, 0, model2.length);
```

the Byte array `model2` easily becomes a bitmap image.

However I need to convert this Array into iso_19794_2 standard so that it can be verified at a web-server.

Note: I don't have access to the server, however I have been informed that it accepts  iso_19794_2 format of base 64 string. Kindly if anyone can help in this case.

Comment: hello @MuhammadAbdullah . have you got any solution? I am also stuck with same issue.

Comment: @KDeogharkar hey mate. Unfortunately not.

Comment: hey dude gont any solution for this?